# retrieve records in asp.net C# MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve some files using the `contact id`

here's my code.

```
    public string Edit(int id)
    {
        var GetContacts = from c in db.Contacts where c.ContactID == id
                        select c;

        return GetContacts.ToString();

    }
```

when I go to `contacts/edit/1` for example. it displays this.

**System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[ContactsMVC.Models.Contact]**

what is wrong with my code? is it in the query. I actually want to get the `name`, `mobile`, and `email` of the user.

I am new to asp.net C# mvc 2 so bear with me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `var GetContacts` returns `IEnumerable<Contact>` so assuming you want that, then your method should be `public IEnumerable<Contact>Edit(int id)` (all you currently doing is returning the `ToString()` value of `IEnumerable<Contact>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes since I don't know how to get the `name`, `mobile` and `etc`. from the object..

Comment: Your returning a collection of contacts (not one) so if you want the first one in the collection it needs to be `var contact = (from c in db.Contacts where c.ContactID == id select c).FirstOrDefault();` and then you change the method to `public Contact Edit(int id)` (and access the properties of the model)

Comment: But since you seem to be wanting to navigate to a controller method, Then it needs to be `public ActionResult Edit(int ID) { var contact = ...as above..; return View(contact); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your return type

```
public IEnumerable<Contacts> Edit(int id)
    {
        var GetContacts = from c in db.Contacts where c.ContactID == id
                        select c;

        return GetContacts.ToList();

    }
```

OR you can return as Json Object

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var GetContacts = from c in db.Contacts where c.ContactID == id
                            select c;

            return Json(GetContacts.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Client Side - (for json one):

```
$.get("yourController/Edit",{id:yourid}, function(data){
   alert(data.Name); // For example
})
```